# injecting NgZone into to angular2 component constructor using appInject vs @inject decorator

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I needed to get a reference to the current ngzone inside of my ng2 component. Looking at the source code, the bootstrap method binds NgZone to the new created instance.

```
bind(NgZone).toValue(zone)
```

This means I should be able to inject this into my component.  My first approach was to declare it in the appInjector array.

```
@Component({
    selector:"todo-app",
    appInjector:[Store, TodoFactory, **NgZone**],
    lifecycle:[onDestroy]
})
@View({ templateUrl: 'todo.html', directives: [NgFor] })
class TodoApp {
    constructor(todoStore:Store, factory: TodoFactory, zone:NgZone) {
    }
}
```

However I this results in the following Error

> Error during instantiation of Token(ComponentRef)!. ORIGINAL ERROR:
>   Cannot resolve all parameters for NgZone. Make sure they all have
>   valid type or annotations.

The work around was to use the @Inject decorator on the parameter.

```
@Component({
    selector:"todo-app",
    appInjector:[Store, TodoFactory],
    lifecycle:[onDestroy]
})
@View({ templateUrl: 'todo.html', directives: [NgFor] })
class TodoApp {
    constructor(todoStore:Store, factory: TodoFactory, **@Inject(NgZone)** zone:NgZone) {
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if this is a bug or intentional?

Comment: From my (limited) use of Angular2, there is no need for the 'Inject' decorator in Beta-0

Comment: I can't help except to say that I'm having this issue in Angular 4.